# Are there any quirks to mobile versions of Chrome or Safari dealing with transform:translate?

Tags: html, css

I have been looking around for some time today trying to find the solution to this. I have a working example that will move an image(technically a background of a div) up the page. This works beautifully on the desktop but on mobile, it doesn't move at all. I'm wondering if this is the fault of mobile not supporting the transform property on the specific element, or if there is something else going on in my code that would mess it up. I also have text on the page that moves down using the same transform property and it still works on mobile. Here's the example I have right now.

http://jsbin.com/qomepe/1

Is there something I just don't know about these mobile versions or is it something I may have messed up in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Many of the mobile browsers do not support all the CSS3 translations and transformations. For instance, rotating text in a mobile browser does not always work, nor does skewing text. That's just the limitations of mobile. I recommend if you want to make it compatible, move the division with some Javascript and/or CSS2 instead.